# Unable to delete the widgets in sub-layout of a layout in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt 5.5.0 for Windows. In a dialog using for login as well as register, I use a QVBoxLayout as the main layout of the dialog and add a QGridLayout to the mainLayout. When I click "Register" button, it will add too more LineEdits for register, and when I click it again these LineEdits will be removed. However, When I remove the widgets in the GridLayout the widgets are still there and the window doesn't resize.

I don't have enough reputation to add images so I upload the iamges here:
http://i.imgbox.com/WAS6KAQw.png

Here's some of my code, so how to remove the widgets in grid layout?

```
LoginDialog::LoginDialog(MainWindow * mw, AgendaService * as, QWidget * parent)
    // Initialization list
{
    // Manage layouts and UI
    passwordEdit->setEchoMode(QLineEdit::Password);
    mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    editLayout = new QGridLayout;
    bottomLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    editLayout->addWidget(usernameLabel, 0, 0);
    editLayout->addWidget(usernameEdit, 0, 1);
    editLayout->addWidget(passwordLabel, 1, 0);
    editLayout->addWidget(passwordEdit, 1, 1);
    mainLayout->addLayout(editLayout);
    QHBoxLayout * buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    buttonLayout->addWidget(registerButton);
    buttonLayout->addWidget(loginButton);
    bottomLayout->addLayout(buttonLayout);
    bottomLayout->addWidget(notifyBar);
    mainLayout->addLayout(bottomLayout);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    // Set default button
    registerButton->setDefault(false);
    loginButton->setDefault(true);

    // Other code
}

void LoginDialog::showRegister()
{
    loginButton->setEnabled(false);
    editLayout->addWidget(useremailLabel, 2, 0);
    editLayout->addWidget(useremailEdit, 2, 1);
    editLayout->addWidget(userphoneLabel, 3, 0);
    editLayout->addWidget(userphoneEdit, 3, 1);
}

void LoginDialog::hideRegister()
{
    editLayout->removeWidget(userphoneEdit);
    editLayout->removeWidget(userphoneLabel);
    editLayout->removeWidget(useremailEdit);
    editLayout->removeWidget(useremailLabel);
    loginButton->setEnabled(true);
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are removing just from layout, not the parent widget, so they are shown in the widget not "layouted".

Try simply hiding them with `setVisible(false)`, and `setVisible(true)` to show them again.

```
void LoginDialog::showRegister()
{
    ...
    useremailLabel->setVisible(true);
    ...
}

void LoginDialog::hideRegister()
{
    ...
    useremailLabel->setVisible(false);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of the [`setHidden( bool )`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setHidden), [`setVisible( bool )`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#visible-prop) functions. If you just use the `removeWidget` function which you did then you only remove it from the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to get rid of the widgets, you should destruct them. If they were allocated on the heap, you should simply `delete` them: this deallocates their memory after destructing them.

Qt keeps track of widget lifetime and a widget being destructed automatically removes itself from its layout, and removes itself from its parent.